# PostgreSQL 9.3: Get list of table names present in view using function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to get list of table names present in the view.

So I have created the function with one parameter(view_name) to get table names.

**Function** :  `funtion_GetTables_FromView`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funtion_GetTables_FromView
(
    view_Name varchar
)

RETURNS TABLE
(
    TableNames varchar
) AS

$BODY$

DECLARE 
    v_SQL varchar;

 BEGIN

    v_SQL := 'SELECT Table_Name  
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
             WHERE View_Name = ''' ||  view_Name || '''';

    RAISE INFO '%',v_SQL;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_SQL;
END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**Calling function**:

```
select * from funtion_GetTables_FromView('myview');
```

But getting an error:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
```

Comment: You are using a parameter `v_viewname` that is no declared in the function header. Also (although, unrelated): you don't need dynamic SQL or PL/pgSQL for this, you can write a simple SQL function that just runs the query and uses the parameter `where view_name = $1`. E.g.: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb27f/1

Comment: Try  -  http://hastebin.com/qoronuqite.sql or alter your existing function like this-  http://hastebin.com/qawocevazu.pas

Comment: @wingedpanther, Hey thank you so much.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thank you so much.

Comment: @wingedpanther: when using a SQL function the cast isn't actually necessary. Apparently SQL has different (automatic) casting rules than dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name +1 for the heads up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only showed a part of the error message, the *complete* error message gives the actual reason:

> ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
>    **Detail: Returned type information_schema.sql_identifier does not match expected type character varying in column 1.**
>    Where: PL/pgSQL function funtion_gettables_fromview(character varying) line 14 at RETURN QUERY

So the column `information_schema.table_name` is not a `varchar` column. The immediate fix for this is to cast the column to the required type:

```
v_SQL := 'SELECT Table_Name::varchar
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
         WHERE View_Name = ''' ||  view_Name || '''';
```

But the whole function is needlessly complex and error prone. A simply SQL function will do just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funtion_GetTables_FromView(v_viewname varchar)
  RETURNS TABLE(tablenames varchar) 
AS
$$
  SELECT table_name  
  FROM information_schema.view_table_usage
  WHERE view_Name = v_viewname;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

For some reason this does not require the cast to `varchar`. I suspect this has something to do with running dynamic SQL inside PL/pgSQL.

---

Unrelated, but: I personally find it pretty useless to prefix a function with `function_`. It is obvious when using it, that it is a function. Are you prefixing all your classes with `class_` and all your methods with `method_` in your programming language?

Comment: Thank you so much for detail explanation and too in minimum time. :)

Comment: Nope! I am not doing that in my work place. That is just for an example. But next time take care of that too.

Comment: You say it is not `varchar` column, but my findings says the opposite `select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_schema='information_schema' and table_name='view_table_usage' and column_name='table_name';`.